# Mysql add default value for all date field

Tags: mysql, alter

I must to change default value for all date field in my database.
Do you know how to do that fast.

Thanks

Comment: update the table definitions in the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) db.

Comment: Do you want to update the existing values or do you need to set a default value when a row is inserted ?

Comment: @Marc B: information_schema tables are read-only (actually, they're not even tables but views)

Comment: ah yeah... true enough. but at least you can query it to find all the date/datetime fields in a db, and then alter those separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that :

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', TABLES.TABLE_NAME, '` ALTER COLUMN `', COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME, '` SET DEFAULT ''2013-02-27'';')

    INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\queries.sql'

    FROM TABLES
        INNER JOIN COLUMNS
            ON COLUMNS.TABLE_SCHEMA = TABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA
            AND COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = TABLES.TABLE_NAME

    WHERE
        TABLES.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
        AND TABLES.table_schema = 'your_database'
        AND data_type = 'date';
```

You'll have to adapt

- the outfile's path (here C:/queries.sql on a Windows server...)
- your database name
- and obviously the default value you'll set (here 2013-02-27).

Then, you'll have to run the output script on the target database.